# How can I use Fabric's/Crashlytics' code to check if a device is jailbroken?

Tags: ios, crashlytics, google-fabric

I want to check if a user uses a jailbroken device. Fabric/Crashlytics uses code to detect if a device is jailbroken as can be seen on a Crashlytics crash page. But I was wondering if I could use that code as well?

On Android the code to check a rooted device is accessible like this: `CommonUtils.isRooted(this)`.

I was wondering if the iOS code of Fabric/Crashlytics also contains code like this that can be used? Of course I can write my own code, but it would be nice to use the code of Fabric/Crashlytics.

Comment: I always thought Crashlytics/Fabric did this by itself for iOS devices. I've had reports of jailbroken devices back in the days, but have not seen them for anytime now.

Comment: @Ramon Yes it does, but I want to use that code myself to check if a user has a jailbroken device. Sorry, did not make that clear enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fabric doesn't have an API to check if the device is jailbroken on iOS. On Android, you could use `CommonUtils.isRooted(this)`.

Comment: That's unfortunate. But you mention that Fabric doesn't provide an API to check if the device is rooted, but as can be seen in my question it actually does. `CommonUtils.isRooted(this)` is a function provided by Fabric. Was there a reason why this is added in the Android code, but not in the iOS code of Fabric?

Comment: I forgot about that on Android, updated my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 3):

For Android, instead of Fabric you can implement Firebase .
There is a similar implementation exit in firebase too.
You can import the following package:-

```
import com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.CommonUtils;
```

and run the code:-

```
if(CommonUtils.isRooted(context)){
  //your code here
}
```